# What happened to the silver border cards? There are none in Unfinity

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

All the cards in the Unfinity (Un-set) are black border. Some have regular round/oval stamps, some have an acorn stamp and some have no stamp.

What do the different stamps means?

Here is a close up of the acorn stamp:
[image: acorn]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With "Unfinity," [WotC decided to retire the silver border and instead mark individual cards in the set as either *Un-* cards or Eternal-legal cards](https://magic.wizards.com/en/news/making-magic/unfinity-and-beyond-2021-11-29).

**The "security stamp" at the bottom of the card replaces the silver border**:

- If you see a standard oval security stamp, or no security stamp at all (for commons/uncommons), that card is Eternal-legal like any normal black-border card.
- If the security stamp is shaped like an acorn, it's a goofy/experimental *Un-* card.

  (Even common *Un-* cards should have the acorn. Look at [Gobsmacked](https://scryfall.com/card/unf/11/gobsmacked), for example.)

That does mean that a bunch of Unfinity cards are Eternal-legal and you can play them in Legacy, &c. Including a bunch of cards that give stickers, which makes Legacy a sticker format now.

---

Unfortunately, mistakes were made in production!

[A bunch of Unfinity cards were *misprinted*](https://articles.starcitygames.com/magic-the-gathering/unfinity-stamp-misprints-cause-confusion-in-first-week-of-sets-launch/), so actually **you have to look up the card on Gatherer or Scryfall to know whether it *should* have an acorn or oval stamp** if there's any question about set legality.

Comment: What about the blank ones with no stamp?

Comment: No stamp is considered the same as a traditional oval stamp, i.e., eternal/"black border". (As you probably know, in normal sets, commons/uncommons don't get a security stamp. In *Unfinity*, they do *if it is acorn*, otherwise they follow the normal rule.)

Comment: (Added clarification)

Comment: It is possibly worth noting that even aside from the issue of printing errors, this was a somewhat controversial decision among some groups of players (as were some of the things they choose to make eternal-legal, such as attractions). That said, it makes sense for Wizards because the ink for those silver borders was not only a spot color (read as ‘made printing more expensive’), but also as I understand it a custom color (read as ‘made printing exponentially more expensive’).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Additionally, the silver and black border cards have to have separate sheets. This makes the collation process more complex as the rarities from each sheet have to be separated out and then merged with each other. With only a single border color they can use their usual process.

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn That's a good point about print costs, though I imagine having to do way more of those little foil badges, and having to stamp cards with different badges (which they immediately messed up) also adds to the costs.

Comment: @eyeballfrog None of which mattered with the previous un-sets, since all the cards were silver bordered, except lands which are on their own sheet (and Steamflogger Boss which was on the land sheet probably for that reason)